# Shifted fractions representing refutational computation trees in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, spacing, fractions, ebproof

I would like to draw a deduction tree in the fractional form shown in the picture, unfortunately I had no luck with `frac` and `over` and I was not able to find better images in the literature.

[image]

Is there a way to draw it with the use of amsmath only (i.e. without TikZ)?

**Edit**: here is what I got after trying what @Zarko (ty) said

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
        \(a, b, \neg c\) & & \(a, b, c\) & & & \\ \cline{1-3}
        & \(a, b\) & & \(a, \neg b\) & & \\ \cline{2-4}
        & & \(a\) & & \(\neg a\) & \\ \cline{3-5}
        \(\qquad\) & \(\qquad\) & \(\qquad\) & \(\square\) & \(\qquad\) & \(\qquad\)
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Try with `array` or  `tabular`. For them you not need to employ `amsmath` package.

Comment: Thank you very much @Zarko, I updated my question with your suggestion.

Comment: I'm glad that you figured out yourself! Happy new year and TeXing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `ebproof` is done for this. The syntax uses a stack like structure.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ebproof}

\begin{prooftree}
                \hypo{a, b, \neg c}
                \hypo{a, b, c}
            \infer2{a,b}
            \hypo{a, \neg b}
        \infer2{a}
        \hypo{\neg a}
    \infer2{\square}
\end{prooftree}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]